# Editor with Code Completion for SDL

Tags: editor, sdl

Is there a code editor that offers code completion and shows the function prototype for SDL?

I ask for an automatic completion like in Notepad++, that shows functions list after like 3 characters have been entered and then show the prototype of the function when the parentheses are opened.

Eclipse offer kind-of what I ask, but it requires <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd> to activate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try QtCreator.

Or KDevelop if you use KDE.

If you need something more lightweight use CodeLite.